# Jquery Validate allowing submit with rules not met

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following form that I am trying to add jquery validate to it. My issue is that none of the validation messages are appearing when I hit submit and if I hit submit twice, the form submits. So, essentially the validation is not working.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

I am using the following libraries:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST" action="" id="proposal-form">
    <div class="panel-input"><input type="text" id="proposal-name" class="proposal-input" placeholder="Name *"></div>
    <div class="panel-input"><input type="email" id="proposal-email" class="proposal-input" placeholder="Email *"></div>
    <div class="panel-input"><input type="tel" id="proposal-phone" class="proposal-input" placeholder="Phone *"></div>
    <div class="panel-input"><input type="text" id="proposal-location" class="proposal-input" placeholder="Location *"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="panel-submit">
</form>

$("#proposal-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         $("#proposal-form").validate({
            onfocusout : true,
             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.appendTo( element.parent("input").next("input") );
             },
            rules: {
                proposal_name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                proposal_email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                proposal_phone: {
                    required: true,
                    digits: true,
                    minlength: 10
                },
                proposal_location: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                }
            },
            messages: {
                proposal_name: {
                    required: "Please enter your name",
                    minlength: "Your name seems a bit short."
                },
                proposal_email: {
                    required: "Please enter your email address",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address"
                },
                proposal_phone: {
                    required: "Please enter your phone number",
                    digits: "Please enter a valid phone number",
                    minlength: "Your number seems a bit short."
                },
                proposal_location: {
                    required: "Please enter your name",
                    minlength: "Your name seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
            var proposal_name = $('#proposal-name').val();
            var proposal_email = $('#proposal-email').val();
            var proposal_phone = $('#proposal-phone').val();
            var proposal_location = $('#proposal-location').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "php/proposal-send.php", 
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        "proposal_name": proposal_name,
                        "proposal_email": proposal_email,
                        "proposal_phone": proposal_phone,
                        "proposal_location": proposal_location
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == "Error!") {
                            alert(data);
                        } else {
                            $("#proposal-form")[0].reset();
                            $('#proposal-panel-inner').hide();
                            $('#proposal-success').fadeIn();
                            function successProposal() {
                                $('#proposal-panel').removeClass('active');
                                $('html').removeClass('is-navOpen');
                                $('.ssm-overlay').fadeOut();
                            }
                            setTimeout (successProposal, 2000)
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: do you have any messages in the console?

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL No messages in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

The markup in your OP's code does not contain `name` attributes.  Without `name` attributes, the validation will not work at all. [See documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations).   Not only must you have `name` attributes, only these names can be used within the `rules` object of `.validate()`.

```
rules: {
    proposal_name: {  // <- this MUST match the NAME attribute only
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
    }
    ....
```

Another major problem here is that the `.validate()` method is enclosed in a `.submit()` handler.  Since the `.validate()` method is simply the plugin's initialization, AND the submit event is already captured and handled internally, you do not need your own `.submit()` event handler.  *(This is exactly why two clicks are needed).*  *EDIT:  A `click` handler is not much different.  It's not needed and makes no sense (emphasis on "initialization", as in `.validate()` is the initialization method).*

```
$("#proposal-form").submit(function (e) {  // <- NOT needed
    e.preventDefault();                    // <- NOT needed
    $("#proposal-form").validate({
        onfocusout: true,                  // <- 'true' is NOT valid
        ....
```

You also do not need `onfocusout: true` because [`true` is not an acceptable parameter for this option](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onfocusout).  The default behavior is to trigger validation on focus out, so setting `onfocusout` to `true` will break this plugin.  It can only be set to `false` or an over-riding function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {         // ensure DOM is ready
    $("#proposal-form").validate({     // initialize plugin
        // rules & options
        ....
```

Finally, the jQuery DOM traversal employed by your `errorPlacement` function does not seem to make any sense based on the posted markup.

```
element.parent("input").next("input")
```

There is no `input` next to the parent of the `input`.  The parent of the input is a `div` and the next element is a `div`.  The next input is *inside* of this `div` that is next to the parent.  It also makes no sense why you'd want to place the error message on the following input element, especially for the last element, which would never display a message.

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/Lhouzn84/](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhouzn84/)**

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I found this was an issue in my own research and eliminated the submit function, as you did and kept the form handler...I also removed the errorhandler (I was just testing it out). Thanks!

Comment: For the form variables, I am having trouble figuring out where to place them. Initially I had them at the top, above the validation `.validate()`, but the values were not sending through (ajax still submitted, just with blank values). I then tried placing them within the submit handler, but now the ajax does not submit. Any ideas? https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=sqa9OgxgJN

Comment: @Paul, I'm not sure why you're asking me this when you've already accepted an answer.  BTW, your new jsFiddle is blank.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change you to having the correct answer, as you were far more in depth and correct. The reason I post this now is because it is essentially the same code, but I changed one part (I now have checkboxes) and since then, my form will either submit not posting the data to my php file or it won't submit the ajax at all. Here is a codepen (jsfiddle isn't saving) https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRwoOa

Comment: First, your selectors don't exist.  For example, `('#proposal-name').val()`, and I do not see any `id="proposal-name"` in your HTML markup.  Secondly, when you grab a value like that, it's the value when the page loads.  If you want the value dynamically, you need to call `.val()` within a function.  In your case, use `('#proposal-name').val()` within the `submitHandler`.  Why not use `.serialize()` to grab the data instead?

Comment: I have it all wrapped in a function ` $("#submit-project").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();` I just thought it would be better if there was less code for you to look at it. The other form inputs I left out, as I think I narrowed it down to the checkbox inputs that are causing the issue (it submitted fine before them). Why would `.serialize()` be more beneficial?

Comment: @Paul, **absolutely** do **not** put `.validate()` inside of a `click` handler... it makes no sense.  As already explained in detail regarding the `submit` handler, `.validate()` is only for **initialization**.  Secondly, `$(form).serialize()` is one line of code versus manually gathering all the values from the entire form, which apparently was another issue as you mentioned.

Comment: I was mistaken, I do not have all of my variables wrapped in the submit function. That was from a different form. I removed it after posting this question. So, for `$(form).serialize()`, I put that within my submit handler by itself and it will grab all the values? I just am not sure how I would send that with ajax though? Then in my php file how to get the values?

Comment: Simply put `$(form).serialize()` as the `data` parameter within `.ajax()` and it will automatically send the entire query string.  In PHP, you just look at the `$_POST` or `$_GET` array, which will contain your data, not any different than when you don't use ajax.  See the edited jsFiddle in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143451/discussion-between-paul-and-sparky).

Answer (score 1):

Edit : Validation rules and message will  match with name of the input element.

Please provide the name of your input control same as specified in Validation rules.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Comment: @Paul, impossible:  This plugin requires that the parameters used within `rules` match the `name` attributes of the inputs.   The `id` attributes will not work here, and your inputs do not have `name` attributes which will also prevent the plugin from working.

Comment: @Sparky I fixed my issue by changing the name, I just didn't correct Ashisha.